# Android - Button disappears at wrong time

Tags: android

So I have a countdown timer as so:

```
final CountDownTimer counter = new  CountDownTimer(800, 1) {

                     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                        textView2.setText(" " + millisUntilFinished);
                     }

                     public void onFinish() {
                        ImageButton imagebutton1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
                        textView2.setText("Game Over!");
                        imagebutton1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     }
                    }.start();
```

This counts down 0.8 seconds and when it finishes it will make the imagebutton disapear.
Unless the button is hit before the timer runs out as shown below.

```
        imagebutton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
         public void onClick(View v)
          {



             counter.cancel();
             counter.start();

             count = count + 1; // Score

             textView.setText(""+count); //Displays Score

            Random r0 = new Random();
            int height = r0.nextInt(1340 - 220) + 220; //Generates new y value

          System.out.println("Height is" + height);

            Random r1 = new Random();
            int width = r1.nextInt(876 - 220) + 220; //Generates new x value
          System.out.println("Width is" + width);
             //finds button

            imagebutton1.setX(width); //changes button position
            imagebutton1.setY(height);
          }
        });             
         }
      }.start(); // Ignore these at the bottom as they are in various different things due to a start timer etc.
```

My problem is that sometimes the timer resets when the button is hit but the button disapears for some reason. I simply can't figure it out. I think it might only happen when the button is hit very close to the end but I'm not sure. I must stress it only occasionally happens, most the time the code functions fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cancelling the CountDownTimer, I would recommend setting up a Boolean value to change when the button is hit. Then, use this as a check in your onFinish method for the timer. I suspect that the cancellation of the timer thread is the problem.

```
// Top of class
private boolean mIsButtonHit = false;

// onFinished method inside of your CountDownTimer
public void onFinish() {
    if (!mIsButtonHit) {
        ImageButton imagebutton1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
        textView2.setText("Game Over!");
        imagebutton1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

// Revised onClick method
public void onClick(View v) {

    mIsButtonHit = true;

    count = count + 1; // Score

    textView.setText(""+count); //Displays Score

    Random r0 = new Random();
    int height = r0.nextInt(1340 - 220) + 220; //Generates new y value

    System.out.println("Height is" + height);

    Random r1 = new Random();
    int width = r1.nextInt(876 - 220) + 220; //Generates new x value
    System.out.println("Width is" + width);
    //finds button
    imagebutton1.setX(width); //changes button position
    imagebutton1.setY(height);
}
```

Then, all you need to do is make sure you set **mIsButtonHit** to **true** in your **onClick** method.

Try it and let me know if it works!

Comment: I will add that the button needs be pressed multiple times, so it won't work will it?

Comment: Rereading your question, the ImageButton may disappear if it is off screen. Is it just flashing off for a moment, or does it stay gone until you reload the app? If it disappears completely, I would use the Layout height values obtained from OnMeasure or get the display size in pixels to make sure you're not going off screen. Try adding debug lines for the X and Y of the button when it disappears, as the Random generator may be occasionally putting it off screen.

Comment: I've tried that, I've been putting the values of X and Y into the console when generated then moving them to the places manually to see if its off screen and it isn't. Ill try adding debug lines though, then I can determine whether the button is still there is whether it's gone. Any idea on how I could make the debug lines? Thanks

Comment: I would say something along the lines of: `Log.d(TAG, "ImageButton X: " + imageButton1.getX() + " Y: " + imageButton1.getY());`

Comment: It really doesn't look like its off screen anywhere, I think it has something to do with the timer's on finish setting the visibility but the button getting registered as hit after and then resetting the timer regardless.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button button;
    private TextView textView, score;
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        counter.start();
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter.cancel();
                counter.start();
                count = count + 1; // Score

                score.setText("" + count); // Displays Score

                Random r0 = new Random();
                int height = r0.nextInt(700 - 100) + 100; // Generates new y
                                                            // value

                System.out.println("Height is" + height);

                Random r1 = new Random();
                int width = r1.nextInt(400 - 100) + 100; // Generates new x
                                                            // value
                System.out.println("Width is" + width);
                // finds button

                button.setX(width); // changes button position
                button.setY(height);
            }
        });

    }

    final CountDownTimer counter = new CountDownTimer(800, 1) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            textView.setText(" " + millisUntilFinished);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            textView.setText("Game Over!");
            button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };
}
```

try this.

Comment: I've just this second manged to fix it, I figured the problem was being caused by the button being detected as hit just as the timer runs out and the loop ending, basically the problem wasn't that the button disappeared, it was in fact that the countdown continued. I just made the text invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I've just this second manged to fix it, I figured the problem was being caused by the button being detected as hit just as the timer runs out and the loop ending, basically the problem wasn't that the button disappeared, it was in fact that the countdown continued. I just made the text invisible